# Position android:windowBackground drawable to the bottom of the window

Tags: android, themes, drawable

In my app, I want the background theme to be white with a drawable at the bottom. Using `android:windowBackground` places and stretches the drawable in the centre. I just need it to be at the bottom. I have `ScrollView`s implemented, so I can't just create a same sized white layout and place it at the bottom, I think.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For others' reference, I simply did the following:

Create a background.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_with_text" />
```

and then I set the background attribute of the required layouts to this. To scale it, the original image should be resized (setting `android:windowBackground` or `android:background` in my theme did not work).